# Is There any way to hide taskbar only on desktop?

Tags: windows, taskbar, desktop-customization

As Title says "Is There any way to hide taskbar only on desktop?"
I mean taskbar work like regular when open explorer,browser etc, in all cases taskbar always show except on desktop.
Windows have option to automatically hide taskbar but it applied everywhere I only want it on desktop.

Edit: If you don't understand what I want just create situation
1.Go to Windows Settings>Personalisation>Taskbar>On the automatically hide taskbar on desktopmode.Now press Win+D.This View I want when I am on desktop.
2.Goto same above and off autohide taskbar and Now open any program or webbrowser.Now See below The taskbar shown all time you don't have to hover it to see taskbar.This is what I want When I open any program open like explorer,web browser,Mail,etc. except on desktop.

I hope you understand and you have answer.

Thanks for Help

Comment: Do you mean: Hide the taskbar when it is empty (no windows)? If not, please explain.

Comment: I want to only  hide when i am on main desktop and when I use browser, the taskbar must be shown below.